# Ruby on Rails - The way to define answers is true / false in model Answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I'm building an online test app. In my app, one question can be a True/False question, Single choice (only one answer is accepted), Multi choice (many answers are accepted). I create models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

The Question model will have a `question_type_id` to check it is a T/F, Single or Multi choice.

The Answer model will have a column called `content` typed text, and i will have a boolean column called `correct` to know which answer is accepted. With single and multi choice questions, i think answers are text will be fine to store in `content` column, but with True/False question, is it good idea if i only store answers is text like 'True', 'False' in `content` column and set a True for answer is accepted in `correct` column? I don't know another better way to deal with True/False question, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the boolean values as strings seems like the most reasonable way to accomplish what you want. I would recommend normalizing the values on save so that true and false always look the same when you fetch an answer.

Comment: can you make me clear what is 'normalizing the values on save'?

Comment: For instance, user A inputs "yes" and user B inputs "T", but the value you check for is always the string "TRUE". When they submit the form, your app could convert any value that means the same thing to "TRUE" to make all of the T/F answers uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have done this kind of app before I can help you....

First of all you should differentiate between the different kinds of questions in your database...Suppose we give Ids to them then we have

0 for T/F Questions 
1 for Single Correct MCQ
2 for Multiple Correct MCQ

Once you have done this, you need to have a different model named as Options,

Question has many options and Question has one answer through options

In the option model, we should 4 columns assuming (option A,B,C,D) it is a four choice questions...

Comment: Yes, i had a question_type model for three kind question. But with your suggest, if i have more than 4 choice, so i have to create more columns in option model? And as i said, a question multi choice will have more one accepted answer, not only one :(

Comment: We can change the association between Question and Answer as has_many :answers :through :options and then it should work as intended becoz the has_many may have one or more association objects...:)

Comment: If you defined has_many :answers throught :options, i think Option model should have a column `option_id`, but you defined 4 column, means an option have 4 answer column, not 4 answer id, so have can you set the right option_id for question?